# HTML table editable on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I am trying to modify a single row in a table. For example `V1` or `V2`, but if I modify `V1` in theory it should only modify `T1`, but this does not work. If I modify the field `V1`, the fields `T1` and `T2` change their values.

```js
 $('#editable').editableTableWidget();
 $('#editable td.uneditable').on('change', function(evt, newValue) {
  return false;
 });

  $('#editable td').on('change', function(evt, newValue) {
  if($("#V1").text()){ 
    $("#T1").text( + $("#A1").text() - + $("#V1").text());
   }  
  });
```

```html
<table id="editable" class="pure-table pure-table-bordered">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Apples</td>
     <td id="A1">10</td>
     <td id="V1">2</td>
     <td id="T1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Pear</td>
     <td id="A2">22</td>
     <td id="V2">2</td>
     <td id="T2"></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`T2` is not changing its value it can only apply new width if `T1` got new `td` width and itcan looks like it was changed but its not.

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fsf2kx42/1/)

Comment: Yes, but.. I only want that, if I modify the value of row 5, for example, only be changed the <td ="T5"> from that row, but this changed me all rows of T1, T2, T3 etc.. with only modify anywhere of my table.

Comment: look at link at my answer

Comment: Ok yes, but I only want that, if I modify V1 only modify T1, Ok yes, if I modify V2 only modify T2 and etc..